# Add a new QuickSight Font

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Does someone knows if it possible to add new Font in QuickSight ? I have to respect my company chart for report and I can’t find the font I have to use.

I have only 8 Font available in the theme creation menu.

Thanks for your help